# How to use a getter with a nullable?

Tags: c#, sql, timeout, nullable, getter

I am reading a bunch of queries from a database. I had an issue with the queries not closing, so I added a CommandTimeout. Now, the individual queries read from the config file each time they are run. 
How would I make the code cache the int from the config file only once using a static nullable and getter. 
I was thinking of doing something along the lines of:

```
static int? var;
get{ var = null;
    if (var.HasValue)
    ...(i dont know how to complete the rest)
```

My actual code:

```
private object QueryMethod(string item)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(item))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand())
        {
            AddSQLParms(sql);
            sql.CommandTimeout = 30;
            sql.CommandText = _cmdText;
            sql.Connection = connection;
            sql.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `is this necessary since....` I don't understand that comment. No it's unnecessary.

Comment: you also should check for DBNull.

Comment: @terrybozzio - incorrect. ExecuteNonQuery doesn't return `DBNull`. Only value or `null`

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry, i forgot to remove that line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var is a system keyword - don't use it

V1 - in this version you expect config to have a value, otherwise error will occur

```
static int? _timeout = null;

private static int GetTimeout()
{
    if (_timeout != null) return (int)_timeout;
    _timeout = GetTimeoutFromConfig();
    return (int)_timeout;
}
```

V2 - in this version you will use default value if config is empty

```
static int? _timeout = null;
private const int def_timeout = 120;   

private static int GetTimeout()
{
    if (_timeout != null) return (int)_timeout;
    int? to = GetTimeoutFromConfig();
    _timeout = (to ?? def_timeout); 

    return (int)_timeout;
}
```

converting from config

```
private int? GetTimeoutFromConfig()
{
    int val;
    bool converted = int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeoutValue"], out val);

    return (converted ? val : null);
}
```

Comment: Open IL decompiler and see

Comment: Assuming his logic returns an int, he should be ok :)

Comment: How would I cover the case where the timeout is not in the config file using your code format?

Comment: command has default timeout. If you worry that command's timeout is not what you need then you can add your default value: `static int _timeout = 120;` Then you will check if the config val is null - ignore it.

Comment: This is what currently happens, when I leave the config value blank "<add key="TimeoutValue" value=""/>", I get this error: "input string was not in a correct format".
BTW, I would vote your post helpful, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: This is different problem. When you read `appSettings`, make sure you use `int.TryParse` rather then `int.Parse`

Comment: Is there a way to convert using 'TryParse'? I currently have **_timeout = Convert.ToInt32.(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeoutValue"]);**

Comment: This is the codeI would expect in `GetTimeoutFromConfig()`. See updated answer

Answer (score 6):

First:  don't call it `var` !

Let's call it `cached_value`.

```
static int? cached_value;

get { return cached_value ?? cached_value = your_logic_here }
```

This way, the first time you call it, if it's null, it'll initialize the field. Next time you call the getter, you'll just get the value you need.

Comment: Your welcome ... Select the answer you like and mark it as answered if you think you got your answer :)

Comment: I am a bit confused on one thing, where in my code block this would be placed?

Comment: same class as you have that query I guess (so it can access it).

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this utilizing the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
public static class ConfigCache
{
    private static Lazy<int> connectionTimeout =
        new Lazy<int>(() => int.Parse(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionTimeout"]));

    public static int ConnectionTimeout
    {
        get { return connectionTimeout.Value; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = ConfigCache.ConnectionTimeout;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to be like you're asking how to use a Nullable variable.

```
static int? val;
get{ 
    if (var.HasValue)
    {
      return val.Value;
    }
    else {
       val = GetValFromConfig();
       return val.Value;
    }
}
```

**var** is a keyword in C#

Comment: damn... you beat me to it

Comment: only by like ... 7 minutes :) don't you find them `??` syntax cleaner?

Comment: is there supposed to be a semicolon after 'val'? and shouldnt there be bracket before the get and a closing bracket at the end or am i missing something?

Comment: those are all there. are you not seeing that?